# Microsoft Stream video Embed code is not working in IE 10, 11

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer-11, sharepoint-online, trusted-sites

I have created simple SharePoint Online classic page and embedded a video uploaded in Microsoft Stream using it's Embed code (iframe). This is working properly in Chrome, Edge and FireFox. But when it comes about IE, the embed code wont work and it says "The video could not be found":

[image]

However, when i open Microsoft Stream app in IE and play video from there, it gets played successfully:

[image]

I have tried almost all solutions that are described e.g. adding stream url in trusted sites etc but no success. Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upload a video using Microsoft Stream and try to embed it in the SharePoint site using an Iframe in IE 11 browser.

Based on my testing result, It is working fine.

Here is the testing result.

[image]

[image]

I suggest you make a test with any other video to see the result. If the issue persists then try to reset the IE. For testing purposes, try to lower down the security settings and check the issue.

For testing purposes, you can try to add that embed code to HTML page to see if video works in IE or not.

Comment: Hi Deepak, I have tried uploading another (mp4) video with permissions for everyone in the organization. Reset IE setttings, embedded in html file and referred that using content editor webpart in a classic page, but nothing is working.
On one of the VM iframe keeps showing 'sign in' to stream link while on my personal machine it shows like the first screenshot in the question.

Comment: I check the MS stream docs and found that it is only supported on IE 11 browser and IE 11 document mode. So this can be the reason that it is not working on IE 10. Try to sign in for MS Stream can show the video on your VM. If the issue persists then I suggest you create a thread on an official MS Stream forum. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-forum/bd-p/StreamForum